# Creating two different subgroups with the same name in TOC in markdown file

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I have markdown file at github: [Awesome AutoHotkey](https://github.com/ahkscript/awesome-AutoHotkey/blob/master/README.md). In groups `Libraries` and `Scripts` we have subgroups with same name `Filesystem`. The problem is that when in the Table of Content I click on the link of subgroup `Filesystem` of group `Scripts` screen jumps to subgroup `Filesystem` of group `Libraries`. Here is sample code:

```
- [Libraries](#libraries)
  - [Filesystem](#filesystem)
- [Scripts](#scripts)
  - [Filesystem](#filesystem)


## Libraries

#### Filesystem

## Scripts

#### Filesystem
```

I need to have subgroups with same name in different groups and I need screen to jump on the corresponding subgroup when I click link for it at Table of Content. How can I do it? Maybe somehow with markdown? Or somehow with html in markdown file? Or maybe some other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That bug was fixed by [hi5](https://github.com/hi5) by adding unique anchor tags for each item in the table of contents. Here is a code of how to do that:

```
- [Libraries](#libraries)
  - [Filesystem](#filesystem)
- [Scripts](#scripts)
  - [Filesystem](#scripts-filesystem)


## Libraries

#### Filesystem

## Scripts

#### Filesystem <a name="scripts-filesystem"></a>
```

Here are [issue](https://github.com/ahkscript/awesome-AutoHotkey/issues/12) and [commit](https://github.com/ahkscript/awesome-AutoHotkey/commit/69b4a07854f23041941824f3189ee278f87c47ac) regarding that bug.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately accepted anwser wasnt working for me, but i found two other solutions. First one is preety strightforward while second one is a bit hacky ツ

### First - use only html tags instad

instead of creating anchor tag just make html tag only, like so:

```
- [Libraries](#libraries)
  - [Filesystem](#Libraries-Filesystem)
- [Scripts](#scripts)
  - [Filesystem](#Scripts-Filesystem)


## Libraries

<h4 id="Libraries-Filesystem">Filesystem</h4>

## Scripts

<h4 id="Scripts-Filesystem">Filesystem</h4>
```

### Second - check what is generated as hyperlink

while you are using autogenerated hyperlink when you are manually clicking on title in markdown preview you can see that it is diffrent when titles are repeating, like so:

```
- [Libraries](#libraries)
  - [Filesystem](#filesystem-)
- [Scripts](#scripts)
  - [Filesystem](#filesystem--1)


## Libraries

#### Filesystem

## Scripts

#### Filesystem
```